# max-height / max-width doesn't function in firefox and ie

Tags: javascript, firefox, gallery, css

Im trying to create a gallery for my website, so i use max-height/width to resize the photo, and it doesnt work in firefox and ie. I also tried overflow: hidden, and didnt fix it.
You can view the problem (in firefox and ie) on my website -- http://guyzyl.org/highlights.html --, click on any photo to see the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: another way would be to calculate new sizes for the images. btw... there is an error in the js - a single s ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning the wrong values to those properties. You're setting the width, for example, to "100%".  That percentage refers to the width of the container element, whose width is that of the whole window. The photo, which is offset on the left by that huge arrow thing, therefore spills off the screen to the right.

You should just use Firebug to play with the property values to come up with something appropriate. You should consider using a percentage to size the arrow control too.

Answer (score 2):

```
vertical-align: top;
```

on your image seems to help, however you should take the advice from @Pointy as what he said is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Setting height with percentages is problematic. try using a pixel there, and also be aware that images are acting differntly when setting width and height than other block element.

I would use a max-height with pixel and set max-width with percents..

Comment: and also set vertical-align:top; @luca +1

Comment: I would like the image to resize based on the browser size, so that wouldn't work